# MonoTouch app cannot build/deploy to iphone device but it works fine on iSimulator

Tags: .net, ios, ios6, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am using the RedLaser binding for Monotouch to create an app that scans barcodes. It works nice like a charm on iSimulator, but when I try deploying to a real device (switch running environment Debug|Simulator -> Debug|iPhone), I cannot even build.

I am using MonoTouch 6.0.8, MonoDevelop 3.0.6, XCode 4.5.2.

Also, I am using iphone 3GS device for deployment. The device is running iOS 6.0 and that is what the target of my application is. I found a bug on MonoTouch bugzilla that has the same erro code [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6998), which suggested changing the target from 6.0 -> 5.1. I did that and did not change a thing.

I have my provisioning profile is setup, verified and installed on Xcode Organiser and same for the Certificate. I can see both are fine.

The Build Output is below, any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks

> > /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++
> >     -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -gdwarf-2  -arch armv7  -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
> >     -c /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/main.armv7.m
> >     -o /Users/hasnainaltaiar/Dev/Leopard/SVN/trunk/LD6419/Platforms/iOS/Leopard.Delivery.iOS/Leopard.Delivery.iOS/obj/Release/mtouch-cache/main..armv7.cache.M0wr77LlBANF6vKjGqQvyVnmWEk=.o
> >     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++
> >     -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -gdwarf-2  -arch armv7  -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
> >     -c /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/registrar.m
> >     -o /Users/hasnainaltaiar/Dev/Leopard/SVN/trunk/LD6419/Platforms/iOS/Leopard.Delivery.iOS/Leopard.Delivery.iOS/obj/Release/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.cache.Zar9bxp0AZNxwVcgrsOMEFHv0k4=.o
> >     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++
> >     -Wl,-no_pie  -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -gdwarf-2  -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.armv7.o
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/Leopard.Domain.dll.armv7.o
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/RedLaser.dll.armv7.o
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/System.Core.dll.armv7.o
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/System.dll.armv7.o
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/monotouch.dll.armv7.o
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/LeopardDeliveryiOS.exe.armv7.o
> >     /Users/hasnainaltaiar/Dev/Leopard/SVN/trunk/LD6419/Platforms/iOS/Leopard.Delivery.iOS/Leopard.Delivery.iOS/obj/Release/mtouch-cache/main..armv7.cache.M0wr77LlBANF6vKjGqQvyVnmWEk=.o
> >     /Users/hasnainaltaiar/Dev/Leopard/SVN/trunk/LD6419/Platforms/iOS/Leopard.Delivery.iOS/Leopard.Delivery.iOS/obj/Release/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.cache.Zar9bxp0AZNxwVcgrsOMEFHv0k4=.o
> >     -o /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/LeopardDeliveryiOS
> >     -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework
> >     AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework
> >     OpenGLES -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -lz
> >     -liconv -u _mono_pmip -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr -u _CloseZStream -u _CreateZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -lmono-2.0 -lmonotouch -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib  -lgcc_eh -force_load /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/libRedLaserSDK.a
> >     Process exited with code 1, command:
> >     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++
> >     -Wl,-no_pie  -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -gdwarf-2  -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.armv7.o
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/Leopard.Domain.dll.armv7.o
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/RedLaser.dll.armv7.o
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/System.Core.dll.armv7.o
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/System.dll.armv7.o
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/monotouch.dll.armv7.o
> >     /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/LeopardDeliveryiOS.exe.armv7.o
> >     /Users/hasnainaltaiar/Dev/Leopard/SVN/trunk/LD6419/Platforms/iOS/Leopard.Delivery.iOS/Leopard.Delivery.iOS/obj/Release/mtouch-cache/main..armv7.cache.M0wr77LlBANF6vKjGqQvyVnmWEk=.o
> >     /Users/hasnainaltaiar/Dev/Leopard/SVN/trunk/LD6419/Platforms/iOS/Leopard.Delivery.iOS/Leopard.Delivery.iOS/obj/Release/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.cache.Zar9bxp0AZNxwVcgrsOMEFHv0k4=.o
> >     -o /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/LeopardDeliveryiOS
> >     -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework
> >     AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework
> >     OpenGLES -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -lz
> >     -liconv -u _mono_pmip -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr -u _CloseZStream -u _CreateZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -lmono-2.0 -lmonotouch -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib  -lgcc_eh -force_load /var/folders/_l/0pvrtd6x6qg83sz4_0906b5c0000gn/T/tmpee06e1f.tmp/libRedLaserSDK.a
> >     Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
> >     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in libRedLaserSDK.a(StatusManager.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 collect2: ld returned 1
> >     exit status
>
> error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
>
> ---------------------- Done ----------------------
>
> Project does not have bundle identifier specified. Generated
>   'leoparddeliveryios' to match provisioning profile.

Comment: Did you forget to include the native dependencies? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104969/monotouch-build-ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-armv7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager"
```

It seems the library was updated and now has a dependency on `CoreLocation`.

Edit the `[LinkWith]` attribute inside the binding project and add `CoreLocation` to it's `Frameworks` property, then rebuild the bindings (and then rebuild your application). If this fixes the issue then please file a bug report so it can be fixed in the github repository.

**Note:** As a quick test you can also add the following option to both your Debug **and** Release configuration of your project (in the **mtouch additional arguments** in your project's Options inside MonoDevelop).

```
-gcc_args="-framework CoreLocation"
```

That will result in the same - except you'll need to copy that fix for every project (and configuration) you're using (so it's useful to spot the issue but not a really good way to fix it).

Comment: Thanks poupou, Adding the "CoreLocation" to the Frameworks attribute on the AssemblyInfo file before binding worked in getting the app to build and deploy to the iphone. However I am getting "SIGABRT while executing native code" error and the app crashes when I load the Controller from the native API binding!! Is this related?? Thanks heaps for the help mate

Comment: Also, I fixed the file on GitHub and sent a merge request to the Author. Hope that helps other people

Comment: I can't say without seeing the full stack trace (even better with a symbolicated crash log). If you can create a small test case (that crash without the hardware) then open a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and we'll have a look :-)

Comment: Thanks poupou, but I cannot reproduce the issue on the simulator because it does not open a CAMERA on the CameraOverlayViewController and that is when it crashes!! is it possible to email you the stack trace??

Comment: It's better to attach the log to the bug report (you can mark it as private if needed) since it's easier to share around when needed (and I can't lose it in my inbox ;-)

Comment: Thanks poupou, I am filing a bug now, appreciate your help

Comment: Poupou, I just filed the bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9592
Please let me know if you need anything to investigate further. Once again, thanks for the help

Comment: I have also attached the link to the project on dropbox to the bug report to make it easy for you to reproduce the issue. Thanks
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2531161/Leopard.Delivery.iOS.zip

Comment: Please use the bug report to add more information (it will be faster than way and everyone will see it).

Answer (score 2):

Ok I resolved the problem but will document the solution here to share the lesson learned.

First: it could not build the solution because it was missing `CoreLocation` from the `Frameworks` attributes when binding. Thanks to poupou for pointing that out, I fixed it also on GitHub (MonoTouch Binding Repo).

Second: MonoDevelop Could not build the app because it could not find the Provisioning profile. You need to set up your Provisioning profile and Certificate manually. You can do that by going to your `Main Project > Options > Build > iPhone Bundle Signing` > Then you choose your `Configuration (Debug|Release)` and `Platform (iPhone|Simulator)` and choose your certificate and provisioning profile for Identity and Prov. Profile.

Third: Lastly, the app was crashing everytime I deploy to the iPhone. I filed a bug as mentioned in the comment above. Then it appeared that RedLaser framework has a bug in scanning QRCodes. Disabling this feature by adding the line below, fixed the problem.

```
overlayController.ParentPicker.ScanQRCODE = false;
```